# Issue in changing VB macro code to VB express 2010 project using Ms-WORD

Tags: vb6, ms-word

I am developing a VB form which will take word document as input from user and will break the document section-wise and create new documents one for each section. I am facing the following issues. 1. I am adapting the code that runs as a macro in word doc to a new project. I am getting errors like

```
'Application' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames'.
'wdStory' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
'wdStyleHeading1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'wdFindStop' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
'wdSectionBreakContinuous' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'Application' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames'.
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
'wdLine' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'wdExtend' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'wdCharacter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'ChangeFileOpenDirectory' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'Application' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames'.
```

I feel they are all similar error and I am missing sm import library?
Pls let me know any library/class that have to be explicitly imported.
Also find the code beloow.

```
Imports System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid file Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
    Dim filextn As String = Nothing
    Dim myfile As String = Nothing

    myfile = TextBox1.Text ' not working

    Dim oWord As New Word.Application
    Dim odoc As New Word.Document
    Dim DocNum As Integer
    Dim onewword As Word.Application
    Dim onewdoc As Word.Document

    'Start Word and open the document template.
    odoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\jy11125t\Desktop\MachineLearning\Doc\1.docx")
    oWord.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal
    oWord.Visible = True

    ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
    Dim iParagraph As Word.Paragraph
    Dim sel As Word.Selection

    ' Inserting section break after every section in the open word doc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Selection.HomeKey(Unit:=wdStory)
    With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting()
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    .Format = True
    ' You can specify another style if you like
    .Style = odoc.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    Do While .Execute
        Selection.Collapse()
        If Selection.Start > 0 Then
            Selection.InsertBreak(Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous)
            End If
            .Execute()
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    ' Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

    'A mail merge document ends with a section break next page.
    'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
    For i = 1 To ((onewdoc.Sections.Count) - 1)

        'Note: If a document does not end with a section break,
        'substitute the following line of code for the one above:
        'For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

        'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard.
        onewdoc.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy()
        'For Each iParagraph In Word.Selection.Paragraphs
        'If iParagraph.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1") Then
        ' filenam = iParagraph.Range.Text
        ' filenam = Left(filenam, Len(filenam) - 1)
        ' End If

        'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
        onewword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        onewword.Visible = True
        onewdoc = onewword.Documents.Add
        onewdoc.paste()

        Documents.Add()
        Selection.Paste()

        ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
        Selection.MoveUp(Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend)
        Selection.Delete(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory("C:\Users\jy11125t\Desktop\MachineLearning\Doc\Split_files")
        DocNum = DocNum + 1
        onewdoc.SaveAs(FileName:=DocNum & ".doc")
        onewdoc.Close()
        ' Move the selection to the next section in the document.
        Application.Browser.Next()
        'Next iParagraph
    Next i
    ' ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    'Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in VB6, in .NET the Word constants (wdExtend, WdStory, etc.) don't automatically become available just by adding a reference. They *are* still available, but you have to qualify them with the namespace they're derived from and they're not all in the same place. The easiest way to find out where they're located is to search using the Object Browser (press F2). For example: wdStory is located in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdUnits.wdStory`

You can skip *most* of the namespace qualifying by importing the common part outside the class code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Then you just need to know which branch each item belongs to:

```
WdUnits.wdStory
WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading
WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakContinuous
WdUnits.wdLine
WdMovementType.wdExtend
WdUnits.wdCharacter
```

Of course this can still seem quite cumbersome, so an alternative is to simply define the constants yourself, assigning the values which can be found in the object browser:

```
Const wdStory As Integer = 6
Const wdStyleHeading1 As Integer = -2
Const wdFindStop As Integer = 0
Const wdSectionBreakContinuous As Integer = 3
Const wdLine As Integer = 5
Const wdExtend As Integer = 1
Const wdCharacter As Integer = 1
```